# Convert C# string to Byte for COM Interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

I am calling a C++ COM component using interop and the marshalling requires one of the parameters to be passed in as **ref Byte**. The argument is actually a string. How do I convert a string (or a char array) to Byte to pass to this method?

Method IDL

```
 [helpstring("method Read")]
    HRESULT _stdcall Read(
                    [in] unsigned char* path, 
                    [in] unsigned char command, 
                    [in] unsigned char nShortAddr, 
                    [out] short* pnDataSize, 
                    [out] unsigned char** ppbyData, 
                    [out] unsigned long* pnError);
```

The IL

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void  Read([in] uint8& path,
                            [in] uint8 command,
                            [in] uint8 nShortAddr,
                            [out] int16& pnDataSize,
                            [out] native int ppbyData,
                            [out] uint32& pnError) runtime managed internalcall
```

The method in the wrapper as seen in Visual Studio

```
    public virtual void Read(ref byte path, byte command, byte nShortAddr,  
out short pnDataSize, System.IntPtr ppbyData, out uint pnError)
```

Comment: Is it really a single byte, and not a `byte[]` or `byte*`? You can't really convert an entire string to a single byte...

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx

Comment: @JasonWatkins : I was thinking the same but that's what the interop marshalling gave me!

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you then. That's just not possible.

Comment: -1 so far: you understand that question as it stand makes no sense so posting is probably of questionable value. It could be much better is you post IDL for the COM object and than people would at least try to reason why you are getting such a strange marshaling.

Comment: Added the IDL, IL and method signature

Comment: @BobbyAlexander `char *` does not mean `ref byte` (it can, but in this case it's probably not). In C++/C an array and a pointer is the same thing, meaning that `char *` and `char[]` is the same. A char-pointer is the normal way to represent strings in C. What you want to do is change your method to something like `public virtual void Read([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string path,......);`. (note LPWStr might be the wrong unmanaged type, just an example).

Comment: I just gave up and wrote a C++/CLI wrapper. End of story. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a poorly authored COM interface.  It can only work when it is used in-process from C++ code.  Which is probably all that the creator had intended.  An argument type declaration like `unsigned char*` is ambiguous, it could mean that a single byte is passed by reference but could also indicate an array of bytes.  You can use attributes in IDL to distinguish between the two but they were not used.  The type library importer therefore could not assume anything else but that this was a `ref byte`.

There's only one decent fix if the source IDL can't be updated, you have to edit the interop library.  Do so by decompiling the existing one first with ildasm.exe.  Then edit the argument type, best done by creating a dummy C# interface with the same declaration as an example.  Put humpty-dumpty back together with ilasm.exe

Comment: Thanks Hans. Unfortunately the component is from a third party and I have no control over it. I just have the tlb and I generated the idl from that. Could you help with what I should change the IL data type to?

Answer (score -1):

#### You cannot convert `String` to `Byte`

But a conversion of `String` to `Byte[]` is possible by using the ASCII encoding

---

String is .Net is - A string is a sequential collection of Unicode characters that is used to represent text. A String object is a sequential collection of `System.Char` objects that represent a string.

you can get String as `Byte[]` using `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(my_string)`

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(my_string)
```